# Can I use gmapping without publishing the map in /map?

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-indigo, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using gmapping but I do not want to publish the map on the topic /map so is there any thing I can do to modify it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285512/can-i-use-gmapping-without-publishing-the-map-in-/map?/) by [roberto3](https://answers.ros.org/users/33776/roberto3/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-03-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My guess is that you want to publish your map on a DIFFERENT topic name rather than /map? If so, you can easily [remap](https://answers.ros.org/question/9248/how-do-you-remap-a-topic/) it.
However, if you don't want to publish your map at all, comment out [line 767,768](https://github.com/ros-perception/slam_gmapping/blob/5a707e079364ab9f5349c72310f31bfed4a6c834/gmapping/src/slam_gmapping.cpp#L767) in your gmapping package.

---

Originally posted by [tuandl](https://answers.ros.org/users/28760/tuandl/) with karma: 358 on 2018-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1